# Show "0" in COUNT column when WHERE does not match?

Tags: php, mysql, count, sql-order-by

What I would like to do is retrieve all data from a table, and order them by the number of games the user played in a specific category. Is there any way I can use some sort of "COUNT WHERE" sql statement?

here's what i have so far. it will only return the user if they have played a game in the "fps" category, but I want it to show all users in descending order even if they have not played an fps game. please excuse my crappy tables

```
SELECT user_data.user, COUNT(played_games.game_cat) as 'count'
FROM user_data, played_games
WHERE user_data.user_id = played_games.user_id and played_games.game_cat = 'fps'
GROUP BY user_data.user_id
ORDER BY 'count' DESC;
```

user_data table

```
user_id | user

1       | jeff
2       | herb
3       | dug
```

played_games table

```
id | user_id | game | game_cat

1  |    2    | kill | fps
2  |    1    | shoot| fps
3  |    2    | COD  | fps
4  |    3    | dogs | cas
```

Comment: Rewrite as a proper left join, with user_data on the left, and played_games on the right. That'd list all users, and give non-null/non-zero counts only for those who've actually played the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I'd do it. No subquery, no COALESCE, no COUNTIF junk.

```
SELECT `users`.`user`, COUNT(`played_games`.id) AS `c`
FROM `users`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `played_games` ON
`users`.`user_id` = `played_games`.`user_id`
AND `played_games`.`game_cat` = "fps"
GROUP BY `users`.`user_id`
ORDER BY `c` DESC, `user` ASC
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e7972/13) (not sure if you can link them like this...)

Comment: Pulls all rows from the left column so that even users with no FPSes played will show in the result set.

Comment: is there a reason that this would work on sql fiddle but not on my dev computer?

Comment: the result is incorrect... it's being ordered by users.user_id.

Comment: That would happen if you had the GROUP BY line but no ORDER BY line... make sure you've copied the above query exactly as it appears, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

You need a [LEFT OUTER JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/outer-join-simplification.html) to get the records even if a corresponding record does not exist in the other table.

```
SELECT user, coalesce(count(game_cat), 0) as count
FROM user_data LEFT OUTER JOIN played_games
ON user_data.user_id = played_games.user_id AND played_games.game_cat='fps'
GROUP BY user_data.user_id 
ORDER BY count desc;
```

Gives the following result on my screen

```
+------+-------+
| user | count |
+------+-------+
| herb |     2 |
| jeff |     1 |
| dug  |     0 |
+------+-------+
```

Comment: are there any advantages to using COALESCE rather than COUNT(if(game_cat='fps',1,null))?

Comment: His initial query was completely wrong. This one is better now that he's edited it, but his ORDER clause is still wrong (note that his results aren't ordered)

Comment: @ddan did you try the latest query?

Comment: i did, but it's not working on my dev computer. it is working on sql fiddle though. any idea why it wouldn't be working on my dev computer?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT ud.user, coalesce(sum(pg.game_cat = 'fps'), 0) Total
FROM user_data ud
LEFT JOIN played_games pg ON ud.user_id = pg.user_id
GROUP BY ud.user_id
ORDER BY Total DESC
```

This will show all users and the amount of times they've played a game with category 'fps'.

Answer (score 1):

The coalesce one is promising, but doesn't work for me, sigh~ I just found NULLIF is a good way to solve this problem. Remember to use LEFT  JOIN

```
COUNT( NULLIF(TABLE.ATTR, 1) ) AS total_count
```

The TABLE.ATTR is some field that can be NULL, here is an example:

```
SELECT Posts.*, COUNT( NULLIF(Comments.user_email, 1) ) as comment_num 
FROM (`Posts`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `Comments` ON `Comments`.`post_id` = `Posts`.`id` 
GROUP BY `Posts`.`id`
LIMIT 5
```

Got the idea from http://www.bennadel.com/blog/579-SQL-COUNT-NULLIF-Is-Totally-Awesome.htm

Comment: Very nice... Sorry for the delay

Answer (score 0):

Below query the all game category with user id and order by count

```
select * from (SELECT user_data.user, COUNT(played_games.game_cat) as 'count' 
FROM user_data, played_games 
WHERE user_data.user_id = played_games.user_id(+) GROUP BY user_data.user_id)
order by count desc
```